# How to restrict non staff users from accessing django-admin

Tags: django, django-admin

My django-admin page is located at

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Suppose there are 3 users in my website.

1. Superuser
2. Staff
3. End user

If anyone of these three users tries to access this link *http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/*, 1st and 2nd can access it.
And **End User** is not able to access it. Till this, it is fine.

What I want is to do is to show Error 404 to **End User**. He/She should never know that this link is for admin page. Moreover, if anyone is not logged in, they should also see same 404 Page.

I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65150331/redirect-non-super-users-to-landing-page-profile-page-if-they-try-to-access-djan) link but it takes me to another default page.

PFA for the same

---

[image]

---

PS: I am using **Signin With Google**, so it should not redirect me there.

I am trying this since 3 continous days, so any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Django-Version: 3. 0. 5**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need to make a custom decorator that would give a 404 if the user is not a staff:

```
from django.http import Http404
from functools import wraps

def staff_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_staff:
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        raise Http404()
    return wrapper
```

Next we will use this decorator as described in your linked question,:

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.login = staff_required(admin.site.login)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**Edit**: Above method was a bit hacky it would show the login pages url to the user even if it gives a 404 error. It would be better to make a custom admin site class and use it. The admin site has a method `admin_view` which decorates the admin views which we shall override. We shall do this in the file `admin.py` in the projects main app (let's say the project is named `myproject`)

```py
from functools import update_wrapper

from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import (
    Http404, HttpResponseRedirect,
)
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect


class MyAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    def admin_view(self, view, cacheable=False):
        def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not self.has_permission(request):
                if request.path == reverse('admin:logout', current_app=self.name):
                    index_path = reverse('admin:index', current_app=self.name)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(index_path)
                raise Http404()
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if not cacheable:
            inner = never_cache(inner)
        # We add csrf_protect here so this function can be used as a utility
        # function for any view, without having to repeat 'csrf_protect'.
        if not getattr(view, 'csrf_exempt', False):
            inner = csrf_protect(inner)
        return update_wrapper(inner, view)
```

Now we need to replace the default admin site with our custom admin site. To do this we will follow [Overriding the default admin site [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site):

In the projects main app's `apps.py` file (assuming project to be named `myproject`):

```py
from django.contrib.admin.apps import AdminConfig

class MyAdminConfig(AdminConfig):
    default_site = 'myproject.admin.MyAdminSite'
```

Now in `settings.py` we will replace `'django.contrib.admin'` with our own config class:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'myproject.apps.MyAdminConfig',  # replaces 'django.contrib.admin'
    ...
]
```

Comment: In which file should I write `custom decorator` for admin. Never used this before. Any referral link is also appreciatable

Comment: @ajinzrathod althoug you can write this in your `urls.py` it would be better to write it in some different file let's say named `decorators.py` (do remember to import the decorator if you write in different file).

Comment: `wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`
Screenshot: https://imgur.com/bI7bdT1

Comment: @ajinzrathod perhaps `method_decorator` is not needed? So `admin.site.login = staff_required(admin.site.login)`. Anyway this method is still a bit hacky I have added a better way to do this in the answer.

Comment: Thank you :) You rock

Comment: You said "Above method was a bit hacky it would show the login pages url to the user even if it gives a 404 error" I did not get this line ?

Comment: @ajinzrathod In that method we are decorating `admin.site.login`, which basically means overriding the login view. What would happen is the user would first be redirected to the login view and then they would be given a 404, so because of the redirect the url (visible in the browsers navigation bar) would have changed to `/admin/login/` even if they had only written `/admin/` which would give an indication that there is actually a page there.

Comment: Appreciatiable explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to [create your own middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) that whenever the path starts with `/admin/` and the user is logged in but doesn't have `is_staff` set to True (both staff and superusers have it), then raise the 404.

```
from django.http import Http404


class NoDjangoAdminForEndUserMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        if request.path.startswith("/admin/"):
            if request.user.is_authenticated and not request.user.is_staff:
                raise Http404()

        response = self.get_response(request)

        return response
```

Then, to activate it, add it to the `MIDDLEWARE` list in your Django settings.

You'll still see the URL with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`, despite seeing a 404 page. If you want to redirect the user to a different page, instead of raising the `Http404()`, then return an [`HttpResponseRedirect()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect).